# Show Background image from tabbar to body Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

with the code below I should show a tabbar as represented in the two images shown.
what I have to do is get the result shown in the image below:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA39Y.png)

[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLiwU.png)

the main problem is that I have to reproduce the layout by overlapping the two backgroudn images as in the result image, below you will find the flutter code, how can I do?

**Flutter Code:**

```
List<Review>? reviewlist;
var u = new Utente();

class LibroView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Book book;
  final String stato;

  LibroView(this.book, this.stato);

  @override
  _LibroViewState createState() => _LibroViewState();
}

class _LibroViewState extends State<LibroView> {
  TextEditingController searctextcontroller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController descrizionecontroller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController titolocontroller = TextEditingController();
  double ratingup = 0;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  Future<bool> getData() async {
    u = await u.getuserinfo();
    var tempreview = new Review(widget.book);
    reviewlist = await tempreview.getreview();
    return true;
  }

  Widget getBookImage(String? url) {
    if (url == "" || url == null) {
      return new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 200.0),
        height: 200,
        width: 100,
        child: Center(
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/librodefault.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 200.0),
      height: 200,
      width: 10,
      child: Center(
        child: Image.network('${url}'),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getImage(String? url) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/rettangolo.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(child: getBookImage(url)),
    );
  }

  void insertreview() async {
    try {
      if (await Review.insert(widget.book, titolocontroller.text, descrizionecontroller.text, ratingup.toString()) ==
          true) {}
    } catch (err) {
      print("errore: " + err.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const SizedBox();
          } else {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0), // here the desired height
                child: AppBar(
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  flexibleSpace: Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/topbar.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10, bottom: 5),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _key.currentState!.openDrawer();
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.menu, color: "#448BB5".toColor()),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          shape: CircleBorder(),
                          primary: Colors.white,
                          onPrimary: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 40, bottom: 5),
                      width: 300,
                      child: TextField(
                        autofocus: false,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          suffixIcon: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 0.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.search),
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          hintText: 'cerca un libro per titolo o autore',
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, bottom: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.7),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.7),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              key: _key,
              drawer: Drawer(
                child: SideMenuWidget(u.nome, u.cognome, u.email),
              ),
              body: Builder(
                  builder: (context) => Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
                        child: ListView(
                          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          children: <Widget>[
                            getImage(widget.book.imgUrl!),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            Row(children: <Widget>[
                              Text("FANTASY",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                      fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                      color: "#AC9359".toColor())),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40, vertical: 5),
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                                    primary: "#F2C94C".toColor(),
                                    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                child: Text('libreria salotto'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 60),
                              Image(
                                image: AssetImage('assets/vector.png'),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 30),
                              Image(
                                image: AssetImage('assets/Vector2.png'),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            ]),
                            SizedBox(height: 5),
                            Text(widget.book.title!,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                    color: '#448BB5'.toColor())),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            Text("Recensioni",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                    color: Colors.black)),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                RatingBarIndicator(
                                  rating: 3,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Icon(
                                    Icons.star,
                                    color: Colors.amber,
                                  ),
                                  itemCount: 5,
                                  itemSize: 10.0,
                                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10),
                                Text(widget.book.productReviewAverage.toString() + " / 5",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                        color: Colors.black)),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text(reviewlist!.length.toString() + " Recensioni",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                    color: "#4F4F4F".toColor())),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Image(
                                  image: AssetImage('assets/line.png'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            new SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Container(
                                child: new ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                  itemCount: reviewlist!.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return new Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              new Container(
                                                height: 30,
                                                width: 60,
                                                child: Center(
                                                  child: RatingBarIndicator(
                                                    rating: 3,
                                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Icon(
                                                      Icons.star,
                                                      color: Colors.amber,
                                                    ),
                                                    itemCount: 5,
                                                    itemSize: 10.0,
                                                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              new Container(
                                                width: 200,
                                                height: 30,
                                                child: Center(
                                                  child: Text('${widget.book.title ?? ""}',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 12.0,
                                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                                          fontFamily: "Roboto")),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              new Container(
                                                width: 200,
                                                height: 30,
                                                child: Center(
                                                  child: Text('${widget.book.author ?? ""}',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: "#828282".toColor(),
                                                          fontSize: 12.0,
                                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                          fontFamily: "Roboto")),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ]),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text("La tua recensione",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                    color: "#AC9359".toColor())),
                            new Container(
                              height: 30,
                              width: 120,
                              child: RatingBar(
                                ratingWidget: RatingWidget(
                                  full: Icon(
                                    Icons.star,
                                    color: Colors.amber,
                                  ),
                                  half: Icon(
                                    Icons.star,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  empty: Icon(
                                    Icons.star,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                itemCount: 5,
                                itemSize: 20.0,
                                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                onRatingUpdate: (rating) {
                                  ratingup = rating;
                                  print(rating);
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              minLines: 1,
                              controller: titolocontroller,
                              // any number you need (It works as the rows for the textarea)
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                              maxLines: null,
                              decoration:
                                  const InputDecoration(border: UnderlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Titolo Recensione'),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              minLines: 6,
                              controller: descrizionecontroller,
                              // any number you need (It works as the rows for the textarea)
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                              maxLines: null,
                              decoration:
                                  const InputDecoration(border: UnderlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Descrizione'),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100),
                                width: 40,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    this.insertreview();
                                  },
                                  color: '#448BB5'.toColor(),
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                  child: Text("Salva",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                          color: Colors.white)),
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBodyBehindAppBar.html

Comment: @rckrd your solution not works